# Moving files using OS and Shutil - Python

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to move a file based on a keyword in a pdf using Python.  What I have so far is this.  PyCharm tells me there are no errors, but I'm obviously missing something since it isn't working.  It's probably something simple but I'm extremely new to coding in general.  Most of this I've pieced together based on stuff I've seen on here.

````
import os

# import PyPDF2
import PyPDF2

#import Shutil
import shutil

#import PDF Search
#Set list of client's to search for
client_names = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"]

#Set Scanned Folder
scanned_path = r'path'


#Create a list of files in folder
scanned_file_list = [os.path.join(scanned_path, f) for f in os.listdir(scanned_path)]
print(scanned_file_list)

#Loop for file searching
for document in scanned_file_list:
    lst = []
    if document[-3] == 'pdf':
        file = open(document, "rb")
        reader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        pageObj = reader.getPage(0)
        text = (pageObj.extractText())
        text = text.split(",")
        source_path = document
        for sentence in text:
            lst = []
            for name in client_names:
                if name in sentence:
                    if name not in lst:
                        lst.append(name)
            if len(lst) > 1:
                file.close()
            elif len(lst) < 1:
                file.close()
            elif lst[0] == client_names[0]:
                #move file to CA folder
                destination_path = r'C:\ClientFolder1'
                shutil.move(source_path,destination_path)
            elif lst[0] == client_names[1]:
                destination_path = r'C:\ClientFolder2'
                shutil.move(source_path,destination_path)
            elif lst[0] == client_names[2]:
                #move file to KB folder
                destination_path = r'C:\ClientFolder3'
                shutil.move(source_path,destination_path)```
````

Comment: May or may not related to issue: pycharm's directory change update on navigator is not immediate if such change is done outside pycharm's navigator, and pycharm's script working directory may not be the script location.

Comment: Isn't working how?

Comment: The files are not moving at all.  I just assumed I did something wrong in the coding.  Some of that I copied and then other I made myself, but I'm also only about 65% of the way through the course on codecademy, so have LOTS to learn still I'm sure.

Comment: From what I can tell it isn't opening the files at all, so bypassing the rest of it.